# Why must the Berry phase in 2d parameter space be $\pi$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I am reading a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9901023) and it seems that the author states that the Berry phase in 2d must be $\pi$. Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which page?

Answer (score 1):

The Berry phase in a 2d parameter space *does not* need to be $\pi$ (or an integer multiple of $\pi$).

Here is a counter example: consider an electron trapped in a box that can be moved in a plane threaded by an Aharonov-Bohm with magnetic flux $\Phi$; the position of the box corresponds to a 2d parameter space. If the magnetic flux is not an integer multiple of the flux quantum $\Phi_0\equiv h/e$, then the Berry phase for a closed circuit $C$ is $\phi_B = n\, 2\pi \Phi/\Phi_0$, where $n$ is the (algebraic) number of times the Aharonov-Bohm flux tube is encircled in the circuit $C$, which is generally *not* a multiple of $\pi$.